# Multi room chat database with mongoDB (mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to set a scheme for a multi room chat which uses mongodb for storage. I'm currently using ***mongoose v2*** and I've thought of the following methods:

**Method 1**

- Each chat log (each room) has its own mongo **collection**
- Each chat log collection is populated by documents (schema) ***message*** with from, to, message and time.
- There is the **user collection**
- The user collection is populated by documents (schema) ***user*** (with info regarding the user)
- **Doubts:**

**1** How exactly can I retrieve the documents from a **specific** collection (the chat room)?

**Method 2**

- There is a collection (**chat_logs**)
- The collection chat_logs is pop. by documents (schema) ***message*** with from, **to** (chatroom), user, etc...
- There is the user collection, as above.
- **Doubts:**

**1** Is there a max size for collections?

Any advice is welcome... thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There is no good reason to have a separate collection per chatroom. The size of collections is unlimited and MongoDB offers no way to query data from more than one collection. So when you distribute your data over multiple collections, you won't be able to analyze data across more than one chatroom.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a limit on normal collections. However, do you really want to save every word ever written in any chat forever? Most likely not. You would like to save say the last 1000 or 10000 messages written. Or even 100.000. Lets make it 1.000.000. Given the average size of a chat message, this shouldn't be more than 20MB. So let's make it really safe and multiply that by 10.

What I would do is to use a [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) per chat room and use [tailable cursors](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/). You don't need to be afraid as for too many connections. The average mongo server can take a couple of hundred of them. The queries can be made tailable quite easily as [shown in the Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-tailable).

This approach has some advantages:

1. Capped collections are *fast* - they are basically fifo buffers for BSON data.
2. The data is returned exactly in insertion order for free - no sorting, no complex queries, no extra indices
3. There is no need to maintain the individual rooms. Simply set a cap on creation and mongodb will take care of the rest.

As for how to do it: Simply create a connection per chat room, save them on an application level in an associative array with the chat room as the key name. Use the connections for creating a new tailable cursors per request. Use XHR to request the chat data. Respond as stream. Process accordingly.

Comment: so are you telling me that I should use a collection for each chatlog? :)

Comment: Not for the log, but for handling the chat. As for the log, you can have a tailable cursor on each of the chatroom capped collections and persist new entries to a specialized log collection, adding the chatroom as a field name. When logging, you can reduce the size of the capped collection, of course. I'd use a very small collection then, maybe 2MB or something.